# function template specialization with return type argument

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Is it possible to specialize a template with an argument for the return value. I am getting an error trying to do the template specialization shown below. So I am currently declaring the two specializations as different functions using macros to 'avoid' duplicating code.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T1,class T2>
inline T1 func(const T2& a) { return T1(3.5);}

template<>
inline float func(const int& a) { return (1.0); }

template<>
inline double func(const float& a) {return (2.0); }

int main() {
  func(2);  
  return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
    temp.cpp:13:3: error: no matching function for call to 'func'
  func(2);      
  ^~~~
temp.cpp:4:11: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T1'
inline T1 func(const T2& a) { return T1(3.5);}
          ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Why not just an overload?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbdd4603f59a6613).

Comment: Overloading > specialization

Comment: You do not want specializations, but simple overloads: "inline float func(const int& a) {}" (no "template<>")

Comment: @AndyG overload for return type? Maybe I am a too confused, but I dont get it

Comment: @tobi303: remove the `template<>` part from your specializations, and you have overloads. It works nicely.

Comment: This is a simplification of a a larger code i have, so I will have to check first.

Comment: @AndyG how can the compiler choose the overload if I do e.g. `std::cout << func(x) << std::endl;`

Comment: @tobi303: The compiler knows what type `x` is at compile-time, so it will call the appropriate function, because one takes a `float` and another takes an `int`. Whichever is a better match gets called.

Comment: Work as expected [Demo](https://ideone.com/6ABYOj).

Comment: Works for me too. http://ideone.com/5JfIkd.

Comment: @AndyG ok, missed the point that the parameter type is different. How about different return types with same parameter types?

Comment: @tobi303: In that case overloading will not work. You would probably template the function on return type, and then call it by explicitly specifying the template arguments. Like CallOverload<int>(float) and CallOverload<double>(float)

Comment: @AndyG thx, now I understand. Sorry for the spam.

Comment: Ok I have reproduced the problem and updated the code. Please take a look again and let me know. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Even the simple example I gave earlier fails. Most examples given in this thread did not call func() in main, and as a result did not expose the problem. I have reverted back to the old example with a simple call to func(2) that will result in the compilation error. Should I post this again as a new question because the interest in this question has evaporated, mistakenly in my opinion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specializing a return type isn't really different than any other specialization. The problem isn't with how this works, but how it is called.

```
template<class T1,class T2>
inline T1 func(const T2& a)
{
    return T1(3.5);
}

func(2); //with T2 = int, what is T1?
```

The compiler has no way to know what the return type should be. A specialization is specific instructions on what to do if the template parameters match, so it still needs both template parameters first. If you specify the first template parameter, it will work.

```
func<float>(2); //returns 1.0
```

As noted in the comments, though, overloading is preferable to specialization.

```
float func(const int&);
double func(const float&);
```

This way, it doesn't get stuck on guessing a return type.

Comment: Thanks that helps on why I can't use the template specialization because I am using it in expression templates where I can't give it the return type argument. As you said in the comment, T2 is figured out but not the return type T1. The overloading solution is what I am using currently with macro and I will keep on using that.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you quite clear what is the problem:

> temp.cpp:4:11: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T1'

You have to provide the template parameter explicitly:

```
int main() {
  func<float,int>(2);  
  return 0;
}
```

The reason is that the compiler cannot deduce the return type that you want to use. `T2` can be determined from the parameter you are passing, but for `T1` any type would make a match, thus the compiler cannot decide.

Comment: That is not the point. I have specified the template argument by giving it an int func(2) and it should select the int version. func(2.0f) should select the other. The overloaded version does that correctly but not the specialization. Why is that? That is what I want to know.

Comment: @user1382302 Why it is I dont know, but thats what the error is saying: could not infer the template argument. Usually this can be fixed by explicilty stating the parameter.

Comment: @user1382302 and what do you mean by "That is not the point." ? When you do it like I suggest, the error is gone ([just tried it](https://ideone.com/DVPJZ1))

Comment: Well I can't use this solution because  I am using it in expression templates where I can not feed the arguments directly like that.

Comment: @user1382302 Specializations and overloads work in different ways. Any overload can be picked equally, so it will find the one that matches best. A specialization can be picked only after the template parameters for the non-specialized function are worked out. Then, it picks the correct specialization, if any. Since there is no way to deduce the return type, it can't proceed to pick a specialization.

Comment: @user1382302 Then you cannot do it. The point is: You specialized some cases, but all other specializations are also valid. For example `func<ANY_TYPE,int>` would be a valid choice for the compiler, so he cannot decide which version to choose.

Comment: @user1382302 I suggest you to accept one of the answers (not  necessarily mine ;) because they answer your question and if you think it is needed you can open a new question with more information included on your actual use case